# connect securely to IoT Edge devices

Tags: iot, azure-iot-edge

I want to secure the connection between the devices and the IoT Edge Device to the secure for example my app running on the iPad access the IoT Edge Device at http://: but I want to access it over https. I am new to IoT, How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a proxy module like outlined here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-modules/edgehub-proxy